# Running a lambda or writing a script?

Tags: bash, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, aws-lambda, amazon-dynamodb

I have a lambda attached to an s3 bucket which would contain historical data(20-25MB). This data would contain folders by months and each month would have over 400k records in txt file. The lambda triggers for every S3EventNotification and would parse the file line by line and save in the DynamoDB table. I need to save historical data in DynamoDB table before launching to prod. Is it better to write a script than running the lambda?

Some of the research that I've done is as file size may be large, lambda can timeout. Also, memory usage is restricted to 512Mb for the lambda.

Answer (score 0):

Your question is a little unclear, but I think you are asking **how to run the Lambda function again over all objects that are *already* in the S3 bucket**.

The easiest method is to [Use AWS Lambda with Amazon S3 batch operations - AWS Lambda](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/services-s3-batch.html):

> You can use Amazon S3 batch operations to invoke a Lambda function on a large set of Amazon S3 objects. Amazon S3 tracks the progress of batch operations, sends notifications, and stores a completion report that shows the status of each action.

[image: S3 Batch Operations]

This way, the Lambda function can be triggered again as if the objects had been freshly uploaded. Note that multiple objects might be passed to a single Lambda function invocation, so ensure that the function is looping through the `event['Records']` list, rather than merely processing `event['Records'][0]`.

If you fear that the Lambda function might timeout, you can increase the timeout to a maximum of 15 minutes. Allocating more memory to a function will also allocate more CPU, which might make it run faster (but costs also increase). After processing a file, be sure to delete it from `/tmp/` to avoid hitting the limit.

However, if objects are bigger than 512MB or take longer than 15 minutes to process, then using an AWS Lambda function is not appropriate.